# Dynamically List Fields from a Database Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Is there a way to query the database to retrieve information about the schema of a table?  I'm interested in just getting a list of the Column names and whether they are primary keys; is this possible? I don't care about the type, just its name and whether it is a primary key.

Sample Table:

```
Table Organism
{
   primary: int ID;
   int Kingdom;
   int Phylum;
   int Class;
   int Genus;
   int Species;
   nvarchar(50) Name;
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
List<Tuple<string, bool>> t = ReadTable("Organism");
t.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Item2 ? x.Item2 + ": " + x.Item1 : x.Item1));
```

Sample Output:

```
True ID
Kingdom
Phylum
Class
Genus
Species
Name
```

I am using C#4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2. I *think* this should be possible using the system tables but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select col.*
from sys.columns col
join sys.tables tab on col.object_id = tab.object_id
where tab.name = @tabName
order by col.column_id
```

The system views contain a wealth of data and they are easy to use.

Comment: Toss in joins to the sys.indexes and sys.index_columns tables to get primary key info.

Comment: I think the PK is in sys.columns. The clustered index is in sys.index, but that is a different concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can get field names with such hacky query

```
select * from Organism where 1=2
```

And Metadata can be retrieved with [Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) , for example key usage:

```
SELECT * FROM databaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
Where TABLE_NAME='Organism'
```